How to send an email when a column changes in excel using Power Automate
My use case is that I've been asked to change our event tracker so that when the column "signed agreement" changes to "signed" and email is sent to our finance guy to process an invoice.
I've tried to set it up this way:

Sharepoint trigger "When a file or item is modified"
List rows in a table
Condition (if Signed Agreement = Signed)
Send an email

This flow works kinda, but sends an infinite loop of emails.
I just want our finance guy to be automatically informed whenever a row in column "Signed Agreement" changes to "Signed".
If there is an easier way that can be achieved without power automate, please do let me know.

There should be an out of the box flow you can use for this on Power Automate. I don't think this is a programming-related question.

You need to show your flow. We’re punching in the dark here.

You need to check if your Status field changed in this modification.

Get changes for an item or a file (properties only)

since: @triggerBody()?['{TriggerWindowStartToken}']
until: @triggerBody()?['{TriggerWindowEndToken}']


Condition

Expression: "equals": [ "@outputs('Get_changes_for_an_item_or_a_file_(properties_only)')?['body/ColumnHasChanged/Title']","@true"]
if true: send emails and other steps
if false: Terminate with Canceled (this is not necessary, but helps on debugging later)



